# Is it necessary to set up a queue for a chat web app

Tags: node.js, redis, socket.io, queue

I'm creating a real-time chat web application using NodeJS and Socket.io, I have plans to save user inputs into MongoDB database. Do I need to set up a key/value store queue system like Redis to keep the application running or it's not really necessary!?
Thank you

Comment: No isn't necessary, you can put some info in a external file, or using localstorage or sessionstorage or a database to store data you can also add to max size and take all of data after a max size to don't call database on every post for insert data but you can do it after a max size, a data.length etc ...

Comment: Maybe I should've added that my concern is inserting data into database on every message sent by users!

Comment: If some people kids fload the chat and you didn't make some secure adding message as filter timer ... etc your database risk to jump hardly and the process too. Now depend of the publics targetting, and the numbers of them, the materials, the network ... etc